# Infinite Product of 2 Matrices

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, infinite-product

Let us assume that I have the $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ where $n$ is finite.

I construct the matrix infinite matrix product $P = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\prod_{i=1}^{N}X_{i}$ and, for each $i$, $X_{i}$ is either $A$ or $B$. In total, $X_{i} = A$ and $X_{i} = B$ for $N_{A}$ and $N_{B}$ instances respectively, with $N_{A} + N_{B} = N$. Let us also say that the ratio of $N_{A}$ and $N_{B}$ remains finite and non-zero (which requires $N_{A},N_{B} \rightarrow \infty$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$).

Let $\sigma_{1}$ denote the (possibly degenerate) largest singular value of $P$ and $\sigma_{2}$ denote the next largest singular value of $P$ that is distinct from $\sigma_{1}$, i.e. $\sigma_{1} > \sigma_{2}$.

Is it true that $\frac{\sigma_{2}}{\sigma_{1}} = 0$ always? I.e. $\sigma_{\rm 1}$ is infinitely larger than any of the other distinct singular values.

Edit: Simple example: $B$ is the identity matrix and $A$ is normal. The singular values of $P$ are therefore $(\sigma_{i})^{N_{A}}$ where $\sigma_{i}$ are the singular values of $A$. Clearly the largest singular value is infinitely larger than the rest as $N_{A} \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: There is no reason in general that an infinite product of matrices is meaningful, i.e., that your limit defining $P$ exists... ! Your question is too fuzzy. You have to be much more precise about matrices $A$ and $B$. Please give a worked example of such matrices $A,B, P$ with $n=2$ for instance. Think for example to take matrices $A$ and $B$ in $SL(\mathbb R,2)$ i.e., with determinant $1$

Comment: @JeanMarie, I have edited the question so that it is, hopefully, a bit less cumbersome. I have also provided a simple example of where it is clearly true, perhaps that is of some help?

Comment: what does this sentence mean  *"Let $\sigma_{1}$ denote the (possibly degenerate) largest singular value of $P$ and $\sigma_{2}$ denote the second largest singular value of $P$, i.e. $\sigma_{1} > \sigma_{2}$."*?   degeneracy typically refers to repeats but you say it is strictly larger

Comment: @user8675309 I mean that $\sigma_{2}$ is the next largest singular value that is distinct from $\sigma_{1}$ (as opposed to being just the second largest singular value), will edit to clarify.

Comment: It will likely depend on how constrained/generalized you define your matrices A and B to be.  If things are completely free, then who knows! But if you're confined to A and B being matrices with real eigenvalues, then maybe you can look into "The Ising Model" and some of the linear algebra physicists use there to simplify "infinite" products.  Assuming that you're basically extending a similar model, I think the first step will depend on whether or not matrices $A$ and $B$ commute nicely.

Answer (score 2):

OP asks

> Let $\sigma_{1}$ denote the (possibly degenerate) largest singular
> value of $P$ and $\sigma_{2}$ denote the next largest singular value
> of $P$ that is distinct from $\sigma_{1}$, i.e. $\sigma_{1} \gt
>  \sigma_{2}$.   Is it true that $\frac{\sigma_{2}}{\sigma_{1}} = 0$ always?

This is not true.  Consider $B:=I_n$  and
$A:= \left[\begin{array}{cc}\frac{1}{m}\mathbf {1_m1_m}^T & \mathbf 0 \\\mathbf 0 & \mathbf \pi\mathbf 1_{n-m}^T \end{array}\right]$
where $\mathbf 1_d$ is the vector of all ones in $\mathbb R^d$ and $\pi$ denotes any non-uniform probability vector in $\mathbb R^{n-m}$

$A$ and $B$ are both idempotent and commute, thus
$P=A$ and $\text{rank}(P)=2$ where $\sigma_1 \gt 1 = \sigma_2$
But $\sigma_1$ is finite and in fact $\sigma_1=\Big\Vert \mathbf \pi\mathbf 1_{n-m}^T\Big \Vert_F= \sqrt{n-m}\cdot \Big \Vert \pi\Big\Vert_2\gt 1$
(e.g. check Cauchy-Schwarz to verify that the inequality is strict)

note: OP also states

> Edit: Simple example: B is the identity matrix. The singular values of
> $P$ are therefore $(\sigma_{i})^{N_{A}}$ where $\sigma_{i}$ are the
> singular values of $A$. Clearly the largest singular value is
> infinitely larger than the rest as $N_{A} \rightarrow \infty$.

This is false. Singular values do not in general multiply for non-normal matrices.  The above idempotent $A$ is a counterexample to this assertion.

Comment: Okay nice counterexample it clearly isn't general. I wonder then under what conditions it is true then - I think it will be true for the vast majority of matrices. I will make an edit about the singular values, that is my bad.